# how to implment a Join SQL command with a Data binding Source

Tags: c#, sql, data-binding

I have a DB that has two tables books and authors.The two tables are joined by the field AuthorID which apperas in both tables.

> Book Table (ISBN, Title, AuthorID)
>
> Author Table (AuthorID, Name)

I have a form that retrieves all the info from the BOOK table and I want to retrieve the Author Name instead of the AuthorID .I want to create a data binding source in Visual Studio that retrieves the author name based on the author ID value. I wrote the sql join query but I do not know how to call to implement in the data binding with C# in Visual Studio

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to bind to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So using linq this is really easy.

Create a Class to hold a record from your joined results.

```
public class Book
{
    public string ISBN {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public int AuthorID {get; set;}
    public string AuthorName {get; set;}
}
```

Create a list or enumerable object to hold your all of your joined results.

```
List<Book> books
```

Take your two sources. Lets call them Books and Authors. Then lets write the join.

```
List<Book> books = from book in BookTable
                   join author in AuthorTable on book.AuthorID equals author.AuthorID
                   select new Book
                   {
                       ISBN = book.ISBN
                       Title= book.Title
                       AuthorName = author.Name
                       AuthorID = book.AuthorID
                   }.ToList();
```

Then lets assign your (ListView?) datasource to that join.

```
lvwBooks.DataSource = books;
```

Also if you would like to do this in flat sql:

```
select Authors.Name, Authors.AuthorID, Books.Title, Books.ISBN from Authors
join Books on Books.AuthorID = Authors.AuthorID
```

And you should be good!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then you should create an SQL datasource and use the custom sql statement that you wrote for the select query.

After you have created the sql datasource you can specify the textfield and the value field in whatever control you are trying to bind to.